# Inner loops for column 2 in imacros

Tags: loops, csv, vbscript, nested-loops, imacros

I am having a problem in form filling. I have two column, both have data, I made a loop for that, but I want a inner loop for column 2, like first it select the row 2 from column 1 and then select data from column 2 until the column 2 over.

For example, I have 10 entries in column one and 20 entries in column 2

- outer loop column 1
- inner loop column 2
- inner loop ends if data in column 2 not found
- again repeat

Here is the code:

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE F:\tgif.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
SIZE X=1392 Y=863
WAIT SECONDS=2.797
DS CMD=CLICK X=589 Y=396 CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS=2
DS CMD=KEY CONTENT={{!COL2}}
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/updatestatus.php?av=100009092062416 ATTR=TXT:Post
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Answer (score 1):

For more complicated iMacro scripts (e.g. with looping and so forth), you can use the iMacro Firefox add-on to run Javascript scripts. Also, in general, for better control it's almost always better to use TAG that targets more specific element attributes (e.g. class, id, etc) instead of by position.

What you want to do sounds like it can be done through a nested loop. If firstField and secondField are arrays, then you could do something like:

```
for (var i=0, alength = firstField.length; i < alength; i++){
    //select first column
    for (var j=0, blength = secondField.length; j < blength; j++){
        //select cell in second column, with the same first column #
    }
}
```

To play iMacro code through javascript, you can use [iimPlay](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay%28%29):

```
iimPlay("CODE: " + m)    //for mac, for windows, you can take out the "CODE: " part, if I remember correctly. Or it might be the other way around!
```

I'm revamping it, so the inclusion part isn't working yet (and some features haven't been added completely)...but I'm working on a javascript library to work with iMacros. You can see it here:

https://github.com/anonmily/iMacroLibrary

If you want, you can use segments of the code or just as help with how to use Javascript with iMacros. To use it, right now, you can just copy what's inside the iMacroLibrary.js document, then add on your own code afterwards. You can minify everything in the library after the "Define unsafewindow" section so that is' a single line, saving space. Then, you can use CSS selectors to select elements on the page and interact with them. You can also import and export CSV data too.

```
var Year = $M('.yearinput');
var Make = #M('.makeinput');

//or 

var Year = $M('select',1); //the first dropdown (select) element
var Make = $M('select',2); //the second dropdown (select) element

Year.click();
Year.extract('TXT')
Make.extract('TXTALL'); //the same as Make.extractAll()
```

To export or import CSV data:

```
exportcsv = function(csvarray, filename);
importcsv = function(file_name, line_num, fields_num);
```

The older version of the library (before I started tweaking with it again...!) Is commit#: 8b6045ecf9559fa7c9e13492d69af067c86a61b5

It's a bit messy towards the end since that's where I put some code for testing, but you can see how it can be implemented that way. Just for reference!

P.S. For automation though, I've been playing around with the Python library Splinter, and it's actually easier to use than iMacros in some ways. The code is easier to write too! I've started to convert some of my old iMacros to Python because of that; there's definitely more power and flexibility. iMacros is great for simple tasks that can be easily/quickly recorded, in my opinion. For web scraping, Beautiful Soup is quite useful too. Also, I've heard about Selenium for web automation as well, though I've not tried it as of yet. Just throwing out some other options out there, just in case. I sure wish I'd known of them earlier!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't how could i merge this code with my iim code.. please merge both code

Comment: No problem. :) I don't know what your csv looks like, or what page/form you're trying to fill in (and what class/id etc describes those input fields)...it's best to just give a try at the problem yourself first, since you'd understand it best. It sounds like a nested array might do the trick.